# Angular - using constant recipe vs value recipe

Tags: angularjs

After I read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) I got curious about something:

Why would I use `value` instead of `constant`? Since constants are avaliable as values **and** also available in the `config` stage

Answer (score 5):

- `Value` can be changed in the runtime, i.e. decorated.
- `Constant` is fixed - can't be changed.

```
angular.module('colors', [])
       .value('favoriteColors', ['red']);

angular.module('main', ['colors']);
       .config(function config($provide) {
           $provide.decorator('favoriteColors', function($delegate) {
               return $delegate.concat(['green']);
           });
       })
       .controller('MainCtrl', function MainController(favoriteColors) {
           console.log('Favorite colors are:', favoriteColors); // red, green
       });
```

Answer (score 4):

Because in opposition to values, constants are compiled and evaluated before the controllers, directives, etc. 
When you need to provide something that should be available to Controllers, directives and what-not before these are compiled and evaluated you should use the Constants recipe.

For example, I like to use the Constants recipe in order to keep my app «magic unicorn strings» clear.

**UPDATE**

Both Constant and Value are injected singletons with a $get method, essentially. Nothing new here.

The main difference between the two is that while a Constant is a value that can be injected anywhere it's value can't be changed down the line of the application's lifecycle because it can not be intercepted by a decorator.

An example of this would be, for example the value of PI. You don't want someone to change the value of PI, so in this case you would define it as a Constant.

On the flip side of the coin, a Value is a simple injectable value. However, it differs from Constants as it can *not* be injected everywhere, for example into configurations, but *CAN* be intercepted by decorators.

So long story short, if what you're trying to define is immutable and you don't want it to be changed during the lifecycle of your app or if you need to inject that service into a configuration you must use a Constant. On the other hand if you're defining a value that will change during the lifecycle of your app then you *must* use the Value recipe.

Hopefully this makes sense, if not let me know.

Comment: Yep but my question was the opposite: why would you use `value` instead of `constant`? `value` looks pretty much like `constant` but with less possible use cases.